# Attribute issue in X-Path expression

Tags: xslt

Below is my input XML

```
          <ServiceIncident xmlns="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
           <ServiceProvider>
               <Person Role="AffectedUser">
                <ContactID>ITELLA_BRIDGE_USER</ContactID>
                <FullName>Chad Whaley</FullName>
               </Person>
           </ServiceProvider>
```

In the output in Person Role i need to get  Role in place of AffectedUser in the above code Role is an attribute for person.Below is my XSLT

```
    xmlns:r2="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
       <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>           
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="r2:Person@Role">
   <xsl:copy>Owner</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It seems what you are asking is a very basic question. Based on your sample XSLT, it seems you have not grasp yet the basic syntax. Try learning the basics first.

Comment: "*In the output in Person Role i need to get Role in place of AffectedUser in the above code Role is an attribute for person.*" Could you rephrase the question? I am not sure what you mean. Showing the desired output would probably help, too. Note also that your input XML is missing the ending part, and your XSLT is missing the starting part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is not valid XML. Hopefully you have valid XML. I'm assuming this:

```
<ServiceIncident xmlns="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
    <ServiceProvider>
    <Person Role="AffectedUser">
      <ContactID>ITELLA_BRIDGE_USER</ContactID>
      <FullName>Chad Whaley</FullName>
    </Person>
    </ServiceProvider>
</ServiceIncident>
```

Your XSLT is also not XSLT, the beginning is missing. I'm assuming that it starts with `<xsl:stylesheet` somewhere.

Under all the assumtions, the XSLT transformer gives me quite a clear error message:

```
'r2:Person@Role' is an invalid XPath expression.
```

This can be fixed to `r2:Person/@Role`.

Next, `<xsl:copy>` does not work for you. Maybe you want

```
<xsl:attribute name="Role">Owner</xsl:attribute>
```

So finally we have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xml:space="default" exclude-result-prefixes="" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:r2="http://b2b.ibm.com/schema/IS_B2B_CDM/R2_2">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="r2:Person/@Role">
    <xsl:attribute name="Role">Owner</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```